# django/apache problem with No module named 'django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

My problem is this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBpUw.png)

I have inscribed the following in my virtualenv [Pip3 freeze image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQ0a.png)

When trying to access my Apache website I get the error 500 and that's why I decided to check the Apache log and I can't understand how to solve it
The log of apache with error is this:

```html
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409034 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895] mod_wsgi (pid=30236): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409188 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895] mod_wsgi (pid=30236): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409444 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409527 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895]   File "/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409550 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.409617 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30236] [client 173.44.36.79:49895] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.813975 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927] mod_wsgi (pid=30238): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.814064 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927] mod_wsgi (pid=30238): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.814249 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.814316 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927]   File "/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.814330 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:06.814373 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30238] [client 173.44.36.79:49927] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226505 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952] mod_wsgi (pid=30237): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226629 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952] mod_wsgi (pid=30237): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226823 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226884 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952]   File "/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226902 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Nov 24 19:06:07.226959 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30237] [client 173.44.36.79:49952] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131087 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653] mod_wsgi (pid=30240): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131215 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653] mod_wsgi (pid=30240): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131406 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131467 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653]   File "/var/www/html/taller_ortiz/taller_ortiz/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131484 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Nov 24 19:13:50.131536 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 30240] [client 68.183.199.94:47653] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: This is my web server: https://tallerortiz.com

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do not post **images** of the logs or errors, instead post the **actual text**. Also, please include *all* information relevant to the question in the **question post** itself!

Comment: [image](https://i.ibb.co/NC1mj08/image.png)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have installed Django for the version of Python used by Apache, or you don't loaded your virtualenv.

Without any other information, I doubt we can give you more help than this.

Comment: Thanks for your answeer, i have install django and python in my virtualenv: [image](https://i.ibb.co/3F5xX7F/image.png)

Comment: Yeah, you just have to make sure that this virtualenv is correctly loaded in your apache configuration.

Comment: Configure Apache in a thousand ways but the problem continues, these are my settings: 
[image](https://i.ibb.co/s5zFGNj/image.png) and my wsgi configuration: [image](https://i.ibb.co/QPgx2v1/image.png)